# Json jquery in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I am trying to create dynamic html created from jquery and save it as json and post to a database using codeigniter. Currently the data is not showing correctly in the database. its just 0. A few issues i am confused with. What should the values of the table be if its storing json data? varchar or what?

I using ajax to post from jquery to a controller in codeigniter

my code from jquery as below

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    //url: "<?php echo site_url('application/models/question_model/jsonAddData');?>",
    url:'jsonAddData',
    //data: cssObject,
    data: item,
    success: function(data) {
            //alert('ok');
        }
});
```

the controller code as below

```
  if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        try{
            $this->load->database();
            $title = $this->input->post('cssObject');
            print_r($title);
            header('Content-Type: application/json',true);
            $query1 = "INSERT INTO testjson (data) VALUES (".$this->db->escape($title).")";
            $query = $this->db->query($query1);
            log_message('debug',$title);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            log_message('debug',$e->getMessage());
            show_error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

When i use chrome developer tools the post is ok. but in the database there is nothing. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive the data like

```
$title = $this->input->post('cssObject');
```

then you have to use

```
data: {cssObject: cssObject} ,
```

in your ajax call.

Comment: hmm what about the database? currently what i see from phpmyadmin is showing nothing.

Comment: what does this line prints `print_r($title);`?